# How do I programmatically call a different URI from inside a REST method in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to create a Jersey call that allows a user to specify a list of URIs to the server as part of a JSON payload, and have the server call each of them and return the results as one big payload (similar to [this scheme](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-execute-multiple-operations-in-batch) employed by Neo4j).

I have figured out a way to get the resource/method that Jersey would call in response to a URI (answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976953/resolve-what-resourcemethod-a-uri-would-match-in-jersey)). But what's a good way to actually call the method, inject its parameters/resource members, and get the return value? Would it be necessary to actually get the object and assemble the parameters manually for each call, or is there some way to hook into Jersey's internals to do it automagically? It's probably impractical to figure out ways to resolve the parameters manually for each possible call.

Comment: Use any Http Client, but you would possibly need the session id. Also, this might not work from a hardware load balancer perspective.

Comment: That would do it, but is it possible to do it without the overhead of making the box interpret all the HTTP headers all over again for each call?

Comment: You probably have a design issue here. That's not how hypermedia links should be followed in REST. Also, you kind of have to interpret all HTTP headers and parameters on each request (content-types, accept headers, etc.).